# Convertion of micro second to hh:mm:ss format

Tags: excel

How can i convert the *microsecond* ****62302456149**** to

> hour minute second

format in Excel.please give me solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below required solution (image link), where hours, minutes and secs are showing separate cells which you can combine to get required format.

[image: Image with Column Names]